# Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver with springboot

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Applicaiton.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  allowedIPPattern: 127.0.0.1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|::1
  jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;INIT=create schema if not exists \"public\"\; SET SCHEMA public;
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    ext.ver = [
            'springboot' : '1.5.3.RELEASE',
            'slf4j': '1.7.12'
    ]

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${ver.springboot}")
        classpath "se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2"
    }
}

group 'com.mycompany'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${ver.springboot}")
    compile ('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38")
    runtime("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
}
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Any idea what am I missing?

I tried to remove:     driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
from yml file. didnt work.

tried to modify build.gradle and version to H2.. also didnt work.

Comment: Maybe the H2 version number in the build.gradle ?

Comment: to which version would you recommend to change this?

Comment: No special recommendation. As example, I'm working currently with "com.h2database:h2:1.4.194" and don't have any problem.

Comment: user user17780 did not read the question well. This is about H2 database, not MySql database. Please reinstate the question. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

try removing the driver name from your application.yml. hibernate should pick be able to pick it up from your url

Comment: removed. got Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver

Comment: Looking at the DataSourceProperties method, it ooks like it's wrapping a classNotFoundError, which suggests the driver is not being imported from dependencies correctly. Check your libraries to see if you can find it there. you may also try setting it to testCompile

Comment: what libs?  I showed you all libs iam import via my build.grade file

Comment: Also tried to set it into testCompile. same stuff